# How to set icon for tex files?

Tags: files, latex, mime-type

In Ubuntu 12.04 with all mate, cinamon, gnome, unity desktops, the following issue:

- I use Latex frequently. My files end with extension `.tex`. The `mime.types` associated with tex is `text/x-tex`. The entry in `/etc/mime.types` for this is as follows: `text/x-tex tex ltx sty cls`
- Thus the icon associated with tex files is the generic icon for all files of text category. I would like to have a special icon for all tex files only. It will make the things easier in finding from a folder which are tex files. How do I achieve it?
- I have tried editing `/etc/mime.types` changing the above line to `text/x-tex ltx sty cls` and then entering another line: `application/tex tex` and then putting a special icon file `application-tex.svg` in `/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetype` and then updating the icon cache (logging out and in again). But that did not show the icon for tex files.

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: There is a strange interaction with icons, thumbnailers and `text/*` mimetypes. See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/589833/different-nautilus-thumbnails-rendering-for-text-files/589903#589903

Comment: @Anita Did you ever find the solution? I have exactly the same question and have tried exactly the same thing. The answers below don't help.

Answer (score 1):

You need a png icon for tex files. edit the icon file as `text-x-tex.png` and then put it to theme mimetypes directory.

For example, I'm using `MBuntu-XL` theme. So, I put the icon file on `/usr/share/icons/MBuntu-XL/mimetypes/scalable/`. Set file permission of the icon file for group and guest as read-only then relogin.

Good luck.