# Different nautilus thumbnails rendering for text files

Tags: 14.04, gnome, nautilus, thumbnails

I have Ubuntu 14.04 Gnome edition on both my laptop and the desktop; both are up-to-date but they have a different past-history of installations and upgrades.

Now, text-type thumbnails are different in the two machines, and I am unable to find where the difference is. This post: [What rendering engine does Nautilus use to show HTML previews/thumbnails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13648/what-rendering-engine-does-nautilus-use-to-show-html-previews-thumbnails) seems obsolete (no entries in `dconf` for them), and [Generate thumbnails for text?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558846/generate-thumbnails-for-text) would help (but it's unanswered).

Look at this composed shot:

[image: thumbnails for text]

In the laptop the thumbnails have a small excerpt of the content of the file (the real content) while in my desktop they are simply blank.

I dug a bit around but I can't find which option/package is responsible of the laptop behavior (which I do prefer, by the way).

How can I enable the "text snapshot" in thumbnails? (And if they had syntax highlighting, like in the linked question, it would be great).

Comment: I see thumbnails for plain text files only when I choose icon themes ubuntu-mono-dark/light and Humanity/-Dark, but not when I use any other icon theme, which I find strange. Could this also be the case with your two different machines?

Comment: @Sadi --- you are on the right track. So there is a thumbnailer override for themes? Do you know where I can find it and change it? My ultimate goal is having the ".tex" icons shown with the text preview and a small logo...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm yet to find those answers as someone who doesn't know much about these matters. I've just asked two themers about this...

Comment: I've begun experimenting with icon themes "Humanity" and "Nitrux" (my favorite); merging two by creating a copy of "Humanity", renaming it, coping all contents of "Nitrux" into this new one, inserting additional directories to the new index.theme file, etc. And now I have the old dark grey "Nitrux" icon for plain text files showing also the contents of each file! :-)

Comment: @Sadi, please post it as an answer when you can!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems for an **icon theme** to let **Nautilus** display the contents of **plain text files** as thumbnails, its sub-directory for mime types, which might be named, for example, **mimes** or **mimetypes** should have a file named **text-x-preview.icon** (along with an icon file named **text-x-preview.png** or **text-x-preview.svg**, etc. serving as a ***backdrop for the file contents thumbnail***), which is actually a plain text file including settings for the thumbnail, in each sub-directory for different icon sizes (for example, 22, 24, 48).

For example, I have added `~/.local/share/icons/Nitrux/mimetypes/48/text-x-preview.icon` (imported from the default **Humanity** icon theme) to my current icon theme, and only then it has begun displaying thumbnails for plain text files, which has the following content:

```
[Icon Data]
EmbeddedTextRectangle=180,100,680,900
AttachPoints=750,750|750,250|250,250|250,750
```

I'll hopefully try and add more information about the settings above in due course.

- It seems having **text-x-preview.icon** and **text-x-preview.svg** (or another valid image file type) in the sub-directory for size **48px** allows Nautilus to display thumbnails for all sizes **from 48px upwards**, but not for sizes below 48px, for which you also need **text-x-preview.icon** and **text-x-preview.svg** (or another valid image file type) at least in the sub-directories for sizes **22px and 24px** (this lets Nautilus to display thumbnails also for 16px in some but not all icon themes).

These two files in the **Humanity** icon theme have exactly the same content:

```
[Icon Data]
EmbeddedTextRectangle=180,100,680,900
```

---

**NOTE: *Unfortunately this whole thing no longer works under Ubuntu 15.04***

Comment: So it seems that is a sort of internal thing of gnome... would be nice to be able to tweak it (decide for example that `text/x-tex` mime type could have a different backdrop. Will wait, marking as solved for now.

Comment: Is `Nitrux` an example, or will that value work for default Ubuntu?

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul yes Nitrux is just an example, it works in any theme, but only before Ubuntu 15.04 or equivalent Gnome version unfortunately.